# Can T have a destructor when std::is_trivial_v<T> is true?

Tags: c++, standards, destructor, type-traits, c++-concepts

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    ~A() {}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<A>); // error   
}
```

It seems obvious that `std::is_trivial_v<A>` will be `false` if `A` has a destructor.

However, from the [cppref page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) of `std::is_trivial`, there is nothing requiring `A` must not have a destructor.

**Can** `T` **have a destructor when** `std::is_trivial_v<T>` **is true?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to go further down the rabbit hole.  The cppreference page says that trivial types need to be [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).  If you visit that page, it has that it needs a

> [Trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor) non-deleted destructor

and if we visit that link we have

> #### Trivial destructor
>
> The destructor for class T is trivial if all of the following is true:
>
> - The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first declaration)
> - The destructor is not virtual (that is, the base class destructor is not virtual)
> - All direct base classes have trivial destructors
> - All non-static data members of class type (or array of class type) have trivial destructors
>
> A trivial destructor is a destructor that performs no action. Objects with trivial destructors don't require a delete-expression and may be disposed of by simply deallocating their storage. All data types compatible with the C language (POD types) are trivially destructible.

So, yes, it needs a trivial destructor and your user provided empty one is not considered trivial.

The only way you can "write" a destructor and have it be considered trivial is to use

```
~ClassName() = default;
```

Comment: tl;dr read more than one or two paragraphs when studying/researching!

Answer (score 2):

> Can T has a destructor when `std::is_trivial_v<T>` is true?

It cannot have a non-trivial destructor. The destructor for class T is trivial if all of the following are true:

> - The destructor is not user-provided (meaning, it is either implicitly declared, or explicitly defined as defaulted on its first
>     declaration)
> - The destructor is not virtual (that is, the base class destructor is not virtual)
> - All direct base classes have trivial destructors
> - All non-static data members of class type (or array of class type) have trivial destructors

Comment: Why does the cppref page not provide the same definitions?

Comment: @xmllmx Because these definitions are on the page that describe destructors.

Comment: @xmllmx The page describing `std::is_trivial` links [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), which links [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), which in turn links to [the same explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor) about virtual destructors.

Comment: @xmllmx If you ask such a (kind of _language-lawer_) question, you may better want to look more at C++ Standards than cppreference. For instance, the relevant part in the current Draft version is [class.dtor/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#8).

Answer (score 2):

When a type is trivial it means it implied it can be destructed trivially.
Explicitly defining a method, like you did will not fit this constraint.
But what you could do is this:

```
struct A {
    ~A() = default;
};

static_assert(std::is_trivial<A>::value);
```